# trying to sum array element values from two different arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, element

I'm trying to sum the value of two array elements from two separate arrays from end to beginning, to see if that sum is greater than 9.

I have tested my code and the part which doesn't work is.

```
if halfa[i] + halfb[i] > 9
```

Does anyone know where i'm going wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 text = gets.chomp


    half1 = text.slice(0,10)
    half2 = text.slice(text.length - 10,text.length)
    puts half1
    puts half2

    halfa = half1.split("")
    halfb = half2.split("")

    halfa.map! { |i| i.to_i }
    halfb.map! { |i| i.to_i }

    count = 0

      for i in halfa.length.downto(0)
          if halfa[i] + halfb[i] > 9
              count += 1
          end
      end

    print count
```

Comment: What does `text` look like?

Comment: How many numbers are supposed to be in each array, cause text.slice(0, 10) is gonna give 11 characters not 11 numbers

Comment: @TravisSmith You are mistaken. The second argument to `String#slice` is a length, not an index. https://repl.it/FXp3

Comment: My bad. A similar issue occurs though, with 10 rather than 11

Comment: You make it harder for us to help you without the minimum input that demonstrates the problem, and the expected output for that input.

Answer (score 2):

You've got an off-by-one error here, one of the classic programming mistakes, you start iterating at `i` being the length of the array, yet `halfa[5]` is `nil`, the array goes from 0 to 4.

The problem here is you're using the clunky `for` loop method for iterating. Ruby, unlike nearly every other language, shuns that in favour of using iterator methods:

```
halfa.each_index do |i|
  if halfa[i] + halfb[i] > 9
    count += 1
  end
end
```

That's the most literal translation of what you have. Note you can clean up your code considerably if it's expressed in a more Ruby-like notation:

```
text = "4443466664"

# Define a variable here that represents the slice size to use
slice_size = 5

# Cut this into groups of 5 characters, convert each chunk by remapping
# the values to integers, then save it all into one variable.
halves = text.chars.each_slice(slice_size).map { |a| a.map(&:to_i) }

# The result looks like this:
# => [[4, 4, 4, 3, 4], [6, 6, 6, 6, 4]]

# Count all pairs that add up to more than 9 using count with a block
# that defines when to count them. Note the use of ... which goes up to
# but does not include the upper bound.
count = (0...slice_size).count do |i|
  halves[0][i] + halves[1][i] > 9
end

# => 3
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to refactor your code would be with [`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [`Enumerable#count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count):

```
text   = "123456789098765"
n      = 10

digits = text.chars.map(&:to_i)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]

first  = digits.first(n)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
last   = digits.last(n)
# [6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
pairs  = first.zip(last)
# [[1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9], [5, 0], [6, 9], [7, 8], [8, 7], [9, 6], [0, 5]]

count  = pairs.count{ |a, b| a + b > 9 }
# 6
```

Answer (score 1):

`for i in halfa.length.downto(0)` : halfa.length is 10, but arrays have zero-based indices: start counting with 0. `halfa[10]` does not exist.

`for i in (halfa.length-1).downto(0)` will result in - well, at least something.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is going to start at `halfa.length`, which is 10. The highest index in in `halfa` is `9`, so `halfa[10]` returns `nil`.

You could fix it by changing `halfa.length` to `(halfa.length - 1)`, but you would still have some very unidiomatic code. In Ruby it's rare to see `for`, because there is pretty much always a better alternative. For example:

```
text = "31415926535897932384"

half_size = text.size / 2

count = half_size.times.count do |i|
  text[i].to_i + text[i+half_size].to_i > 9
end

puts count
# => 4
```

The above code assumes that the text will have an even number of characters. You could also hard-code `half_size` to 10 if you wanted.

The [`Integer#times`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Integer.html#method-i-times) method will enumerate the numbers 0 through its receiver, so e.g. `5.times.to_a` returns `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. The [`Array#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-count) method returns the number of times the block yielded a truthy value.

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/FXpa